# Disable word-wrap by default in Sublime "Find in Files" results

Tags: sublimetext

Sublime's "Find in Files" (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>) search results always have word wrap on by default. This is really annoying whenever a file containing a single huge line of text gets caught in the results, since:

- wrapping the huge line takes ages and slows Sublime (and perhaps the whole computer) to a crawl, and
- it makes the results difficult to read, since the wrapped line may take up screens and screens of space

It's possible to disable word-wrap from the "View" menu, but this change doesn't persist after closing the "Find Results" tab.

Is there a way to turn off word wrap for all Find Results?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, with the Find Results tab active (ensure the "Use Buffer" option is enabled in the Find in Files panel to get a tab instead of an output panel when you perform the search), you can navigate to the `Preferences -> Syntax Specific` menu item and enter:

```
"word_wrap": false,
```

and save it. This will ensure that word wrap is always disabled for Find Results.

(You can always turn "Use Buffer" off again afterwards, it's only necessary for the menu item to open the correct syntax specific settings file, which is `Packages/User/Find Results.sublime-settings`.)

Comment: More precisely, it's `Preferences` -> `Settings - More` -> `Syntax Specific - User` on my machine (though perhaps that's platform-dependent).

Comment: it could also be related to which version of Sublime Text you are using - I believe it was changed in build 3116.

Answer (score 4):

In default, Sublime opens the files without word wrapping. If you want to enable it, just go to Preferences > Settings and add `"word_wrap": true` to the `Preferences.sublime-settings` file

[image]

Comment: This works, but disables word-wrap for ALL files, not just search results. Personally, that's not what I want, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41144999/1709587 is a better solution - but maybe for some people your answer is the better option!